# Webpack: node_modules/css/index.js didn't return a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying out webpack for the first time and used [this tutorial](http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/) to get started and include react.js.

After finishing the steps and installing the `style` and `css` module I keep getting an error that the css module didn't return a function.

This is my index.jsx:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

'use strict';

require('../css/normalize.css');

var React = require('react');
var Hello = require('./Test/Hello');

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

And my webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './ui/src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build-ui',
        filename: 'app.js', //this is the default name, so you can skip it
        //at this directory our bundle file will be available
        //make sure port 8090 is used when launching webpack-dev-server
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style!css"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: "style!css!sass"
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        //don't bundle the 'react' npm package with our bundle.js
        //but get it from a global 'React' variable
        'react': 'React'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

When webpack tries to bundle the project it always states the following error:

```
ERROR in Loader /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/css/index.js didn't return a function
 @ ./ui/src/index.jsx 5:0-31
```

I don't know what to do about that. Has anyone encountered that issue? And how can I solve it?

**EDIT:** My directory looks as follows:

```
holmes/
  ui/
    css/
      normalize.css
    src/
      Test/
        Hello.jsx
      index.jsx
    index.html
  package.json
  webpack.config.js
```

Comment: What sort of directory structure do you have?

Comment: By the way, I have [a working setup](https://github.com/bebraw/react-component-boilerplate) in case you want to compare it against yours.

Comment: I added the hierachy to the question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This error is caused by a `css` module inside `node_modules`. Since you've specified the `css`-loader in your config, webpack tries to lookup that loader inside `node_modules` and finds another module called `css` which doesn't look like a loader (hence the error message).

To avoid confusion you should simply add the `-loader` postfix to each loader. Omitting the `-loader` postfix is just a convenience feature by webpack, but unfortunately it's the culprit of that error in your case.

```
    loaders: [
        {
            //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        }
```

*Update: Starting with webpack 2, you can't omit the `-loader` postfix anymore. We decided to do this to prevent errors like this.*

Comment: Do you think it's preferred to use `-loader` suffix always?

Comment: Well ... most of the time I don't write it because I like the brevity. But in this case, it was the cause of an annoying error. So, if you want to avoid such errors, yes, you should probably always write it :)

Comment: Couldn't figure out why a babel submodule devDependency was being pulled in and this ended up being the cause. Simply using "babel-loader" fixed things. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks, adding the -loader postfixes and also npm installing `css-loader` and `sass-loader` did the trick for me!

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue with `react-flexbox-grid`. In my case, the solution was installing `css-loader` and `style-loader` npm modules:

```
npm install css-loader style-loader --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came across a similar issue using `node-noop`.

Fortunately, using `null` as a replacement worked when I added `enzyme` and `react-addons-test-utils` to a project.